# jquery adding class but dom not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a variant of a page in console of the browser (https://direct.asda.com/george/women/dresses/ochre-ruched-front-floral-print-midi-dress/GEM652507,default,pd.html). The issue i am having is when i click on thumbnail the main image is not changing. Main slider should update when i click on thumbnail, slider arrows,pagination. and vice versa. thumbnail shoud show selected when clicked on arrow or pagination. I just want my code to work on browser console.

below is my code:

```
$(function(){

$(".inspirational-right").hide();           
    d = document.createElement('div');
    $(d).addClass("thumbnail")
    .insertAfter($(".product-name" ));
$( ".swiper-slide.image-slide" ).clone().appendTo( ".thumbnail" );
$(".inspirational-left").css({"width": "100%","float": "right", "position": "relative"});
$(".thumbnail").css({"position":"absolute","z-index":"999","width": "140px", "height": "600px", "float": "left", "top": "1px","overflow": "hidden"});
$(".thumbnail > .swiper-slide.image-slide").css({"z-index":"999","transform": "scale(.18,0.18)","height": "112px", "width": "71px","cursor":"pointer"});
$(".swiper-container.custom").css({"margin-left":"200px"});
$(".thumbnail > .swiper-slide.image-slide").click(function(){
  $(".thumbnail > .swiper-slide.image-slide").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  var imgId=$(this).attr("data-imageid");     
  $( ".swiper-container .swiper-wrapper .swiper-slide.image-slide" ).each(function() {
    $(".swiper-container .swiper-wrapper .swiper-slide.image-slide").removeClass("swiper-slide-active");  
    $(".swiper-container .swiper-wrapper .swiper-slide.image-slide").removeClass("swiper-slide-visible");      
    if($(this).attr("data-imageid")===imgId){
      $(this).addClass("swiper-slide-active");
    }        
  });      
})
 });
```

updated with fix and suggestion

Comment: your selector looks wrong `.thumbnail > > img.singleImage` you either need something in between the arrows or If it's a direct child then remove one of the arrows

Comment: There is a missing semicolon after `$(".thumbnail > > img.singleImage").removeClass("active")`. Is that a copy/paste error, or is it also in your real code?

Comment: Also, having searched the source of the page, there is no thumbnail class - please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [mcve] demonstrating your problem

Comment: @PhilippMaurer It should not cause issues in most browsers. But yeah it's a good habbit to fix it.

Comment: updated with fix and suggestions

Comment: but still not working